# Como gerar gráficos a partir de um arquivo utilizando um loop em R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

Gostaria de a partir de um arquivo, que no caso é de indicadores de segurança pública do rio de janeiro, gerar gráficos para cada ano da base de dados, mostrando o avanço desses indicadores ao longo dos meses. Infelizmente a ideia inicial que tive, que está abaixo, não funcionou.

```
# link do site com os arquivos utilizados 
# Séries históricas do estado por mês desde 1991 (números absolutos)

http://www.ispdados.rj.gov.br/EstSeguranca.html

# Leitura do arquivo 
Ind_mensais <- read.csv(file = "DOMensalEstadoDesde1991.csv", sep = ";",
  dec = ",")

# Loop que filtraria por ano as informações e geraria um gráfico
library(ggplot2)
for(i in 1992:2019){
    ano<-filter(Ind_mensais,vano == i)
    ggplot(ano,mapping = aes(x =mes,y=latrocinio))+geom_line()
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Por definição, o `ggplot2` não plota os gráficos se eles estiverem sendo gerados dentro do um loop. Para que os gráficos apareçam, é necessário plotá-los explicitamente através da função `print`:

```
library(ggplot2)

for(i in 1992:2019){
  ano<-filter(Ind_mensais,vano == i)
  print(ggplot(ano,mapping = aes(x =mes,y=latrocinio))+geom_line())
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Note que isso vai gerar os gráficos para cada ano, mas eles não estarão identificados. Sugiro criar um título para cada gráfico, através da função `labs`. Além disso, utilizo a função `paste` para criar uma string dinâmica, atualizada para cada valor de `i`:

```
for(i in 1992:2019){
  ano <- filter(Ind_mensais, vano == i)
  print(ggplot(ano, mapping = aes(x = mes, y = latrocinio)) +
          geom_line() + 
          labs(title = paste("Latrocínios em ", i, sep = "")))
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se quiser que os meses apareçam com seus nomes em vez de número, é necessário transformar a coluna `mes` de numérico para data. Recomendo instalar e carregar o pacote `lubridate` para isso:

```
library(lubridate)

Ind_mensais <- Ind_mensais %>%
  mutate(mes = month(mes, label = TRUE, locale = "pt_BR"))

for(i in 1992:2019){
  ano <- filter(Ind_mensais, vano == i)
  print(ggplot(ano, mapping = aes(x = mes, y = latrocinio, group = 1)) +
          geom_line() + 
          labs(title = paste("Latrocínios em ", i, sep = "")))
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Caso queira escrever os nomes dos meses por extenso ou de outra maneira, recomendo ler a documentação da função `scale_x_date`.

Comment: Muito obrigado, era exatamente esse detalhe que estava faltando e os rótulos nos meses irão melhorar muito a visualização.

Answer (score 1):

Para ler os dados a função `read.csv2` é mais apropriada, pois já tem como separador de colunas o `";"`.
Pode plotar todos os anos no mesmo gráfico com `facet_grid` ou `facet_wrap`. Neste caso vou usar a segunda função.
A ideia de transformar os meses com o pacote `lubridate` deve-se à [resposta do Marcus Nunes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/428011/82237).
Vou ainda rodar 60 graus a anotação do eixo dos x.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

fls <- "DOMensalEstadoDesde1991.csv"
Ind_mensais <- read.csv2(fls)

Ind_mensais %>%
  mutate(mes = month(mes, label = TRUE, locale = "pt_BR")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = mes, y = latrocinio, group = vano)) +
  geom_line() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 60, hjust = 1)) +
  facet_wrap(~ vano)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Muito obrigado, pode ser realmente uma boa alternativa para apresentar todos os anos de uma só vez.

Answer (score 0):

Já faz algum tempo, mas vou tentar agregar mais uma resposta utilizando as funções `tidyr::nest` e `purrr::map`. De forma geral, é uma possibilidade mais completa em termos `tidyverse`. Todos os gráficos gerados vão estar no objeto `gg` criado e cujo título é o ano da série.

```r
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)

Ind_mensais <- read.csv2("DOMensalEstadoDesde1991.csv") %>% 
  mutate(mes = month(mes, label = TRUE, locale = "pt_BR")) %>% 
  group_by(vano) %>% 
  nest(.)

NEST <- set_names(Ind_mensais$data, sprintf("%s", Ind_mensais$vano))

gg <- map(names(NEST), function(w){

  z <- NEST[[w]]

  z %>% 
    ggplot(., aes(x = mes, y = latrocinio, group = 1)) +
    geom_line() +
    labs(title = w)
})
```

<sup>Created on 2020-02-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>